# windows 10 compatible free picture editor with snap-to-grid option

Tags: windows, image-editor

I'm designing tiled platformer games level maps. I know there are Tile editors around, but I'm used to create levels from images of levels, copying bits and blocks to create new rooms & zones (then I use an import program to convert to "logical" tiles).

Basically, I used to:

- export the image from my custom tile/level editor (which can only perform very basic operations, like create tile, delete tile...) as .png
- load the .png in the image editor & modify it
- save back as .png
- import the image in my custom tile/level editor

For that I need "snap to grid" feature, configured as the size of a tile so when I copy/paste blocks, they automatically align to a multiple of the tile height/width.

I was using an excellent software a long time ago: *Jasc* Paint Shop Pro 7 (yes, it's *very* old)

It was simple, fast, not bloated. Unfortunately, it doesn't work on Windows 10 anymore. Version 9 barely works (not on my laptop it doesn't). I don't want to run a virtual XP machine to run them. That would make that solution more complex because of VMWare, file sharing...

So I tried Corel (which bought Jasc software) versions (X7 and X9) and though they have the feature, they are so bloated my computer takes ages to load and even to work once loaded (I have a i5 processor), not to mention I'd have to buy them and they're not cheap.

I have looked to find an image editor with this feature and failed. Any suggestions ? (a free editor would be a plus).

EDIT: in the meanwhile I tried Gimp 2.10 and found it very good (much better than the multi-windowed old versions). There's this snap to grid/snap to guide option, but it doesn't seem to work. Maybe a configuration problem?